# Ionic 2 Cordova web app browser console errors (GET example.com/screen 404)

Tags: cordova, web-applications, ionic2

Ionic 2 / Cordova 7.0.1

Getting these Chrome console errors and I don't know where from.

```
GET https://www.example.com/screen 404 ()
GET https://www.example.com/null 404 ()
```

Plugins used:

```
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="~1.8.4"></plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.5" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.4" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.1" />
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~2.3.0">
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: @Gandhi app.component code or which?

Comment: the project code that makes any ajax calls

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue with `/screen`, the problem comes from the default cordova config. Find the line

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
```

in config.xml and replace the value field with an existing path, for example:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="assets/logo.svg" />
```

I did not have the problem with `/null`, so I can't answer for this part, but this should be the same problem.